# How would I go about mixing front/rear audio channels to a powered subwoofer?

Tags: audio

I'm looking at installing a small powered subwoofer under my seat. Most conventional guides for doing this suggest putting the subwoofer on either the front or rear speakers to get a mono setup.

My stock radio comes with come front/rear fading based on who you want to hear the audio, driver only, whole car, or backseat only that I make somewhat common use of. For this reason, I'd like to have all four channels going to the sub and mixed evenly. What sort of hardware would I need to mix the front/rear left signal and the front/rear right signal to create two balanced signals that would go into the left/right posts of a powered sub?

Comment: My other alternative is of course getting two powered subs, one to put under the drivers seat, another to put under the passengers seat, and just mix the signals to those two subs 

Comment: the bay of fleas has stereo to mono converters...

Comment: You may find your radio already has a mono sub output on the rear panel, or a stereo "line" output that will drive a powered sub.